# AngularJs params give all objects with one id

Tags: angularjs, http, parameters

I want to get a single object from `json` file using `AngularJs` params, but it give me all objects.

This is the code I've used,

```
 (function () {

    "user strict";

    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .controller("indexCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

        var workId = $routeParams.id;

        $http({
            url: "data/work.json", 
            method: "GET",
            params: {id: workId}
        }).then(function(sitedata) {
            $scope.workDetail = sitedata.data;
        });  

    });
})();
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: If you're loading a json file it will just return the whole content, you'll have to filter in the `then` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading a json file it will just return the whole content, you'll have to filter in the `then` callback:

```
$http({
    url: "data/work.json", 
    method: "GET"
}).then(function(sitedata) {
    var match = sitedata.data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id == workId;
    });
    if (match.length) {
        $scope.workDetail = match[0];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks bother its working, i am newbie in angular so that why. any thanks its help me.